# Change Windows password in a web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, iis, workgroup

I have a web site using https and basic authentication. User is automatically authenticated against Windows. The web site is hosted on a workgroup computer (not member of a domain). I'm working with .NET Framework 4 and C#

I try to change the password of the user from a web page (after the user is authenticated) without success. I tried several things using DirectoryService like :

```
    using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format(@"WinNT://localhost/{0}, user", userName), domainAndUser, userPassword))
    {
        directoryEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldPassword, newPassword });
        directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
```

I receive an access denied error. I guess I need to be admin to do this.

Is what I try to do possible and how to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Christian

Comment: Are you using a MembershipProvider or using IIS Authentication?

Comment: Changing people's Windows passwords through a website? How can that possibly go wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to run that code on the server or on the client?

Comment: Thanks all for answers. No I'm not using a membership provider, just IIS authentication. Code runs inside a web application.

Comment: @user957479 - try using `WinNT://<machine name>` for your path. I think the path you're passing to `new DirectoryEntry` is wrong. That may then work within a LAN, but I think the whole approach is doomed to failure if the client is off in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run that code impersonated as administrator on your workgroup computer, have a look at [ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [ASP.NET Runtime Impersonation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107940/Back-to-Basic-ASP-NET-Runtime-Impersonation)